# Baking normals from hatch frame to body work

Tags: normals, baking

I'm trying to get these hatches to bake as normals onto the bodywork under them so I don't need to have the game render the whole thing. (obviously. :P ) Unfortunately I'm still VERY new at this and this is the first time I've ever tried to bake a normal map, usually I just model the stuff I want. I followed various tutorials but it never seems to come out anything like what I want. I assume I've buggered up either the modelling or the settings for the bake. All the normals are orientated the right way (Blue). Can anyone give me a quick run down of the step by step to get this to work? Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Thanks so much!

The hatches I'd like to use as normals.

[image]

The bodywork under the hatches, unwrapped and ready to go, in theory.
[image]

One of the results that baking brings.
[image]
Attempt number 2.
[image]

Comment: if your shapes are completely parallel or perpendicular to the faces that are baking, you won't have any result as baking the normals will only take face orientation into consideration (parallel or perpendicular can't be baked), it may be the problem here? I don't know why you have the second result though... Maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/5ed48387e5fb4baf864ed16ba1ac33d8   So it wouldn't be able to baked the raised hatches onto the side of the body work? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is duplicate your main object, you'll call the duplication the "high-poly", boolean it with your hatches so that you get that:

[image]

If the faces of the high-poly are parallel of perpendicular to the faces of the low-poly that are baking, the bake won't catch anything as baking normals is supposed to record the orientation of the faces (perpendicular or parallel faces won't be recorded and will remain blue):

[image]

So scale the hatches face down a bit so that their sides are not completely perpendicular to the wall faces that will bake them:

[image]

Choose the *Selected to Active* option. Give a bit of *Extrusion* to the bake (like 0.1) because the faces of the hatches of the high-poly go a bit beyond the surface of the low-poly, so you need to make the bake start a bit before the faces of the low-poly. Now if you bake you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh well explained, thank you! That's gotten most of it working, one side worked perfectly, the other side is yellow-y brown? https://imgur.com/a/xZUfjzb

Comment: it looks like inverted normals? maybe share your file again

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/7c87946a3ad54e4b95e22d2f9a9bea23 There you go. :) They seem fine to me? They aren't red, i assume thats what you mean? :) Thank you so much for the help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: increase the extrusion value a bit, like 0.05. Also unplug the Normal map of the high poly material

Comment: Ahh that's got it. So just fiddle with that value if it doesn't display quite right? :) Do I need to do anything with 'Max Ray Distance'? I just left it on 0.

Comment: just play with the Extrusion value, it allows to move the start of the bake, it is useful when the high-poly surface goes beyond the low-poly surface, which is the case here with the hatches. I don't remember what's the Max Ray Distance, probably the length of the bake scan (how far it goes), you don't need it here

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much! Much appreciated. :)